# Load multiple value File into ArrayList in JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a file with this kind of content:

> accountNumber=1000, branchName='11', balance=420, customerNumber=1

> accountNumber=1001, branchName='11', balance=323, customerNumber=2

I have a method that reads the content and loads it in to the `ArrayList` but :

```
private static void loadAccounts() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
static ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("AccountFile");
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
    accounts = (ArrayList<Account>) objectInputStream.readObject();
    objectInputStream.close();
}
```

but after I call `loadAccount()` I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid
> stream header: 6163636F   at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:938)
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(ObjectInputStream.java:396)     at
> Main.loadAccounts(Main.java:151)  at Main.main(Main.java:18)

Comment: ObjectInputStream is for serialized data, not random text

Comment: You should look into a JSON-based solution.

Comment: you should probably read line by line in file, and store accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't have a solution to automatically convert these lines to your `Account` object, you will need to implement it yourself. Here's an example of how to make it work, assuming the line pattern doesn't change:

```java
    private static void loadAccounts() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
        final FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("AccountFile");
        final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();

        while ( line != null) {
            final String[] split = line.split(",");
            final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            for (String entry : split) {
                final String[] keyAndValue = entry.split("=");
                map.put(keyAndValue[0], keyAndValue[1]);
            }
            Account account = new Account();
            account.setAccountNumber(map.get("accountNumber"));
            account.setBranchName(map.get("branchName"));
            account.setBalance(map.get("balance"));
            account.setBranchName(map.get("customerNumber"));
            
            accounts.add(account);
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }

        fileReader.close();
        bufferedReader.close();
    }
```